# How to create a wavy shape and the transition animation?

Tags: angular, animation, carousel, mousehover

I wish to replicate the first carousel in [patreon.com](https://www.patreon.com/) website in Angular V16.2.12.

Is there any particular name for that particular hover effect? Is it manipulating some SVG to make the hover effect possible?

I tried to do it with my understanding but nothing is working.

Comment: You can animate `clip-path` with `svg` `path` elements' path properties. There are many ways to do this, so start by sharing what you did try.

Comment: I did try this, but was not working! have any good resource related to this?